# MS Access Software Tracking Sheet

Tags: sql, ms-access, database-design

Im looking to see if i can create a database with MS Access.

I've got the jist of using Access but when i'm designing my tables im having some trouble finding something common to use between the tables.

So far I have.

**Table Name:** Software
SoftwareID - Auto-increment *Primary Key*
SoftwareName: Short Text
DateCreated: Date/Time

**Table Name:** User
UserID - Auto increment *Primary Key*
FNAME: Short text
LNAME: Short text
DateCreated: Date/Time

**Table Name:** Department
DepartmentID - Auto-increment *Primary Key*
DepartmentName: Short Text
Position: Short Text
DateCreated: Date/Time

anyone have any suggestions on what i can use to link the tables

Comment: You should explain what you want to "link".  Do you mean you want to relate users to departments, e.g. each user belongs to a department, or each software belongs to a department, or the many-to-many association between users and the software they use?

Comment: I was planning on relating Software to department and just for tracking purposes software to user.

Id say software per department is the main idea but just in case any reports have to be done software to to user would also be convenient.

Comment: Does each software entity belong to only department and user, or can it belong to multiple departments and users?

Comment: Hmm, i would say depending on the software, each software entity can belong to multiple departments and users. 

for example of an software entity
MSOffice can belong to multiple departments and users within that department

Answer (score 0):

To relate two entity sets in a many-to-many relationship, create a new table in which pairs of keys are recorded.  For example:

```
DepartmentSoftware (SoftwareID PK/FK, DepartmentID PK/FK)
UserSoftware (SoftwareID PK/FK, UserID PK/FK)
```

In both tables, we make both columns part of the primary key since it's the combination of the two values that are unique (this makes it a many-to-many relationship, if only one column was included in the primary key it would be a one-to-many relationship).  We also add foreign key constraints to ensure that nonexisting software, departments and users don't get inserted or left behind.

Comment: ahhhhhhhhh ok makes sense,

so my tables should be like

Tablename: DepartmentSoftware
SoftwareID - Primary key and foreign key
DepartmentID - Primary key and foreign key

Tablename: Usersoftware
SoftwareID - Primary key and foreign key
UserID - Primary key and foreign key